# Sidekiq causing memory bloat in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a rails app with sidekiq workers performing processes in the background and originally had around 30 threads to perform tasks. We found this was causing high memory usage and reducing the thread count for the workers reduced the memory bloat, but I don't understand why. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: Was it memory leak (i.e. constantly increasing memory consumption)? How much memory the sidekiq instance had? By my experience it should be at least 4gb for 30 sidekiq workers

Comment: It was just much larger than expected; around 1 - 2GB per worker.

Comment: Do you manage the memory leak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a quick google it sounds like you are experiencing memory fragmentation which is pretty normal for Sidekiq. Are you using class variables at all? Does your code require classes during execution time? How many AR queries are you executing? Many AR queries create thousands, if not millions, of objects and throw them away. *Is your code thread-safe?* As per [this post](https://www.mikeperham.com/2018/04/25/taming-rails-memory-bloat/) from the author of Sidekiq, we can see memory bloat happens from a large number of memory arenas in multithreaded applications. There are some details of a solution in that article and even the readme of the Sidekiq repo that are very helpful, but it might be worth outlining the causation to understand why memory bloat happens in 'rails/ruby'.

Memory allocation in Ruby involves three layers: interpreter, OS memory allocator library and the kernal. Ruby organises objects in memory arenas called `Ruby heap pages` and a ruby heap page is divided into equal-sized slots, where one object occupies a slot. These slots are either occupied or free and when Ruby allocates a new object, it tries to occupy a free slot. If there are no free slots, it will allocate a new heap page. Each slot has a byte limit and if an object is higher than the byte limit, a pointer is placed in the heap page to the object.

Memory fragmentation is when these allocations happen and is quite frequent in high thread applications. When garbage collection happens the heap page marks a cleared slot as free and allows the slot to be reused. If all objects in the heap page are marked as free then the heap page is freed back to the memory allocator and potentially the kernal. Ruby does not promise garbage collection on all objects, so what happens when not all free slots are freed and there a large amount of heap pages that are partially filled? The heap pages have available slots for Ruby to allocate to but the memory allocator still thinks they are allocated memory. The memory allocator does not release the entire OS heaps at once and can release any individual OS page, just once all allocations are released for said page.

So threading plays an issue as each thread try's to allocate memory from the same OS heap at the same time and they contend for access. Only one thread can perform an allocation at a time, which reduces multithreaded memory allocation performance. The memory allocator attempts to optimize performance by creating multiple OS heaps and tries to assign different threads to its own OS heap.

If you have access to ruby 2.7 you can call `GC.compact` to combat this. It provides a way to find objects that can be moved in Ruby and condenses them and reduces the amount of heap pages used. Empty slots that have been freed through GC in-between consumed slots can now be condensed against. Say, for example, you have a heap page with four slots and only slot one, two and four have an object assigned. The compact call will evaluate if object four is a movable object and will assign it to slot three and any references associated with the object and redirect to slot three. Slot four is now placed with a `T_MOVED` object and the final GC replaces the `T_MOVED` object with `T_EMPTY`, ready for assignment.

Personally, I would not rely solely on `GC.compact` and you could do the simple `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX` trick, but have a read of the source documents and you should find a suitable solution.